# How to mock a React.MemoExoticComponent (React.memo) with jest using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

In my project, I am using React + typescript and jest + Testing-Library/react for testing. I am trying to mock a functional component wrapped in React.memo. With "normal" components I take this approach:

```
jest.mock('../SearchComponent');

const mockSearchComponent = SearchComponent as jest.MockedFunction<
    typeof SearchComponent
>;
```

which then allows me to mock different implementations, e.g.

```
    mockSearchComponent.mockImplementation((props: Props) => {
        /* do something with props */
        return <div />;
    });
```

When attempting to do the same with a functional component wrapped in React.memo:

```
jest.mock('../PaginationComponent');
const mockPaginationComponent = PaginationComponent as jest.MockedFunction<
    typeof PaginationComponent
>;

mockPaginationComponent.mockImplementation(
        (props: PaginationComponentProps) => {
            return <div />;
        }
    );
```

VSCodium does not seem to find any problem with it, hovering over mockPaginationComponent, it shows

```
const mockPaginationComponent: jest.MockedFunction<React.MemoExoticComponent<({ start, rows, toNumber, totalNumber, onPaginationUpdate, }: {
    start: number;
    rows: number;
    toNumber: number;
    totalNumber: number;
    onPaginationUpdate(start: number, rows: number): void;
}) => JSX.Element>>
```

However, when I run jest, I get the error

```
TypeError: mockPaginationComponent.mockImplementation is not a function

      88 |      };
      89 |
    > 90 |      mockPaginationComponent.mockImplementation(
         |                              ^
      91 |              (props: PaginationComponentProps) => {
      92 |                      return <div />;
      93 |              }
```

And when I remove the mockImplementation and instead try to e.g. expect a call to the mockPaginationComponent, such as:

```
renderWithRouter(<PersonSearch />);

            expect(mockPaginationComponent).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
```

I get the error:

```
    expect(received).not.toHaveBeenCalled()

    Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

    Received has type:  object
    Received has value: {"$$typeof": Symbol(react.memo), "compare": null, "type": [Function mockConstructor]}

      261 |                     renderWithRouter(<PersonSearch />);
      262 |
    > 263 |                     expect(mockPaginationComponent).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
          |                                                         ^
      264 |
```

Am I missing something in my jest config? Do I have to add another test layer to kindof mock the React.memo as well? I would have expected to be able mock the component wrapped in React.memo just like a "normal" component.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, and I resolved it by exporting the component and the memo separately.

```
export const MyComponent: React.FC<MyProps> = (props: MyProps) => {};
export const MemoizedMyComponent = React.memo(MyComponent, compareFn)
```

in the implementation, use the memoized version

```
return (
<div><MemoizedMyComponent props={props}/></div>
)
```

In the test, mock your non-memoized function as per usual and your test will simply memoize your mocked function instead.

Comment: For future answers, I can recommend formatting code adequately (e.g.: with Prettier). Formatting increases the readability and thus the quality of the answer.

Comment: Hi @TPiddy and thanks for your answer!
I don't have access to the codebase anymore, but I'll try to recreate the situation to check if it works for me. Just so that I get this correctly, the test is smart enough to memoize the non-memoized function as long as there is also an export for a memoized function?

Comment: @hogreflector by mocking the non-memoized function, the implementation just memoizes the mock instead. You need the export for the memoized function for your implementation, and an export for the non-memoized function for the test.